# How to upload a file without the submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, multer

I am trying to have my upload button upload a file to a temp directory without needing to click a submit button but i get an error stating : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path').

```html
html.js     

<style>     

input[type="file"] {
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
top: 15px;
left: 20px;
font-size: 1px;
color: #b8b8b8;
}
.button-wrap {
    position: relative;
}

</style>
<div class="button-wrap">
     <form id="fileUploadForm" action="/fileUpload" 
          enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
          <label class="button" for="upload">Upload File</label>
          <input id="upload" name="upload" type="file" 
          onchange="fileUploadForm.submit()">
     </form>
</div>
```

```js
node.js 

app.post('/fileUpload', upload.single('filetoupload'), (req, res, err)=>{

var filepath = req.file.path
filename = './public/temp/' + req.file.filename
var jFile =  filename + '.json'




console.log(req, fileStorage, "filename: ",filename, "filepath: ",filepath, "jFile,",  
jFile);

res.status(204).end();
});
```

Comment: Did you console.log the req object?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `req.files`?

Comment: @Ouroborus That's what I am suspecting too. Although it's a bit of a weird behavior, when specifying "single".

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html <-- no it should not be files

Comment: The whole problem here is the invalid HTML closes off the form and the file input is not in the form. Fix the bad HTML as I said 15 minutes prior to this comment. And set up your IDE to detect HTML problems so you do not find yourself in this situation again.

Comment: @epascarello I fixed the html  and it receives the following error: MulterError: Unexpected field and one of the places its pointing is the css for the button wrap (input[type=file] etc... ill include that above as well.

Comment: @MatthewWithington You changed the name.... so of course it will complain upload != filetoupload

Comment: @epascarello smh.. rookie mistake on my part. Works fine now thanks!

Comment: @epascarello I know that is **should** be req.file, but in fact I have a working project with single upload where req.file is undefined and the file is contained in the req.files array.

Comment: @ISAE that is not the issue im having it turned out to be a simple html mixup. The console logs the file properly through req.file.etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Your HTML should be:
```

```
<div class="button-wrap">
         <form id="fileUploadForm" action="/fileUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
            <label class="button" for="upload">Upload File</label>
            <input id="upload" name="upload" type="file" onchange="fileUploadForm.submit()">
        </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).